# same page transparent intro

Tags: php, wordpress, css-float

we are looking to place a semi-transparent welcome image on a clients Wordpress main index page, exactly like this http://www.editionsof100.com/.

I suspect this has been created using Jquery, would be possible to create something similar by adding to the CSS or index.php on WP?

Comment: ugh intros are so terrible, I remember seeing a comic about a greeter @ a store, who blocks your door saying, hello welcome to our store, and you just want to get around them and go in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple, but pointless IMHO:

Create a div wherever you want the image located:

```
<div id="hello"><img src="http://tonkapark.com/projects/hello.png"></div>
```

Then you just use `.fadeOut()` on the element. Standard & simple jQuery

References:

- http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/
- http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using rgba values?

Example:

`div { background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5); }`

If you need some animations, check out this cool css library which it is very easy to use.

[enter link description here](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)